# How load image in this code?

Tags: java, android, json, image, load

I have a class ImageLoader, FileCache, MemoryCache and utils, but I do not know how to implement images load in this code, can anyone help?
My address with JSON is still IP I have not turned in the domain, if one is required API to write a comment...
It is a all for ListView...

```
private static final String TAG_OBJECTS = "objects";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "ime";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_MOBILE = "telefon";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "opis";
private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "slika";

// objekti JSONArray-a
JSONArray objects = null;

// Hashmap za ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> informacijaLista;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false); 

    new GetContacts().execute();
    return rootView;
}
 @Override 
 public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      informacijaLista = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        ListView lv = getListView();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                        .getText().toString();
                String email = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                        .getText().toString();
                String telefon = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                        .getText().toString();
                //ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
                String image = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image)).getImageMatrix().toString();

                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        SingleInfoActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                in.putExtra(TAG_MOBILE, telefon);
                in.putExtra(TAG_IMAGE, image);

                startActivity(in);

            }
        });  
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
     // TODO Add your menu entries here
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // Handle presses on the action bar items
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.refresh:
             new GetContacts().onPostExecute(null);
             return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
         default:
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
 }

/**
 * asihrona klasa za JSON poziv preko HTTP protokola
 * */
 public class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // prikazivanje progres bara
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Ucitavanje informacija...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // instaciranje servis klase
        Servis sh = new Servis();

        //uzmi adresu
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, Servis.GET, null);

        Log.d("odgovor: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                objects = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_OBJECTS);

                // LISTANJE svih objekata tj informacija
                for (int i = 0; i < objects.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = objects.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String image =  c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

                    HashMap<String, String> info = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    info.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    info.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    info.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                    info.put(TAG_IMAGE, image);


                    informacijaLista.add(info);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Servis", "Url adresa nije validna");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // za odbacivanje progres dialga
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         *  azuriranje podataka u list viewU
         * */

        //ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), informacijaLista,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { 
                                                    TAG_NAME,
                                                    TAG_EMAIL,
                                                    TAG_MOBILE,
                                                    TAG_IMAGE
                                                    },
                                    new int[] { 
                                                    R.id.name,
                                                    R.id.email, 
                                                    R.id.mobile,
                                                    R.id.image
                        });
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}}
```

Comment: You cannot call an AsyncTask like `new GetContacts().onPostExecute();` use `new GetContacts().execute();` For the rest I didnot inspect your code yet.

Comment: You have to load your images in getView(). Please show your code.

Comment: Everything is fine with the code, just need to load image, but thank you for the view that error for onPostExeceute :D

Comment: You have two accounts?

Comment: There is no function getView()?

Comment: No greenapps, I have one accounts

Comment: Then who is user3414471? Look for `getView` in `class SimpleAdapter`.

Comment: I do not know who is user3414471..
SimpleAdapter?
I have singleactivity...
looks like my packages
com.app
Contacts.java
SingleActivity.java
Servis.java
com.app.image
FileCache.java
ImageLoader.java
MemoryCache.java
Utils.java

Comment: Aha.. My mistake. You use SimpleAdapter and that is an Android widget. So then I have to ask you: what does not work? Please describe why you don't see images.

Comment: The application is run ok, it does not display an error in the log.
look this 
String image = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image)).getImageMatrix().toString();
I thought I need to convert the image that I showed

Comment: This is very unclear to me. What are you doing? Does it display images? R.id.image will be an ImageView. What sense does it make to extract a String from it? Are images displayed in your listview? Your matrix is only when you open a second activity.

Comment: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: wahels.jpg
in log this show...
Do not display images

Comment: Sorry i do not understand you. In this way i cannot help you.

Comment: Thus, my application works ok, but the problem is that I do not know that display images in listview from url address.
http://77.105.36.203/api/v1/info

Unable to decode stream:

Comment: http://77.105.36.203/media/info/wahels.jpg

Comment: now ok, but not show!